# How to change column title in table that was created by tabulator.js?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I use latest version of tabulator.js and I need ability to change column title in tables that already exists. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. In your case I would recommend to go through the [docs and tutorials](http://tabulator.info/) and try to grasp the general approach for what are you trying to achieve..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the column has been created it cannot be changed, but you can remove the existing column and replace it with another column with an updated definition:

remove existing column:

```
table.deleteColumn("fieldName");
```

add column:

```
table.addColumn({title:"Age", field:"age"});
```

More details can be found in the [Column Definition Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/columns#replace)

Comment: Is this still true since its was asked 2 years Old? If it is its a shame. I imagine it would e great to be able to set the title to be editable (show it shows as an input), type the new title and when they exit the input it updates the title

Comment: http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/columns#edit-titles

Answer (score 1):

My hack job workaround

Declare element in column definition.

```
title: "<myTitle>Title</myTitle>",
```

change it like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("myTitle")[0].innerHTML = "myNewTitle";
```